# Display data in a Vue component with ajax

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I seem to be misunderstanding how to pass data to a Vue.js component with an ajax call.

My understanding of how this should work:

- I need to create an empty object called campaigns in the data section of my component.
- Then call method "fetchCampaigns" on page ready to replace the data object.
- fetchCampaign method completes an AJAX call and inside of the success callback  use this.$set('campaigns', campaigns)  to replace the empty campaign object with the newly returned campaign object
- Use v-for on the template to iterate through the campaign object and access values with @{{campaign.type}}

My html (I am use vue router, vue resource and laravel blade) :

```
<router-view></router-view>

<template id="campaignBlock" v-for="campaign in campaigns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="block"> 

                <div class="block-title">
                     <h2>Type: <em>@{{campaign.id}}</em></h2>
                </div>

                <div class="row"><!-- Grid Content -->
                    <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-4 col-lg-4">  
                        <h2 class="sub-header">@{{campaign.title}}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- END Grid Content -->
</template>
```

Vue component

```
Vue.component('app-page', {
template: '#campaignBlock',

data: function() {
    return{
        campaigns: []
    }
  },

ready: function () {
    this.fetchCampaigns();
},

methods: {
    fetchCampaigns: function () {
      var campaigns = [];
      this.$http.get('/retention/getCampaigns')
        .success(function (campaigns) {
          this.$set('campaigns', campaigns);

        })
        .error(function (err) {
          campaigns.log(err);
        });
    },
}
})
```

This is the result of my ajax call from console:

```
{"campaigns":[{"id":1,"user_id":2,"target_id":1,"name":"Test Campaign","description":"This is a test Campaign","target":"Onboarding","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","deleted_at":null}]}
```

I'm not sure why I can't get my vue component to recognize the new data.  Anyone see what I'm missing?  TIA

Comment: When you think about it, it makes complete sense that it doesn't work.  The template tag declares that it's contents are a template - in this case, a vue template.  If you aren't in the content, vue ain't gonna work.  In other words, your v-for isn't in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that v-for="campaign in campaigns"  should not go on the template tag, but inside of it.

So this:

```
<template id="campaignBlock" v-for="campaign in campaigns">
            <div class="row">
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<template id="campaignBlock">
            <div class="row" v-for="campaign in campaigns">
```

Comment: Also, you should close the `div.block` tag.

Comment: @retrograde, Seems you master vue.js. I need your help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843823/how-to-display-button-link-with-vue-js