# How to display button link with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My view is like this :

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-store-info">
    ...
    <div id="app">
        <AddFavoriteProduct></AddFavoriteProduct>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

My component is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteProduct({{ $product->id }})">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        name: 'AddFavoriteProduct',
        props:['idProduct'],
        methods:{
            addFavoriteProduct(event){
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_product: this.idProduct}
                this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteProduct', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When click button favorite, it will call controller on the laravel

I had register on the app.js like this :

```
...
import AddFavoriteProduct from './components/AddFavoriteProduct.vue';
...
components: {
                ...
                AddFavoriteProduct
            },
...
```

When executed, the button favorite does not appear.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

There exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. (found in root instance)

Whereas I had register it

Comment: Are you using any other component or this is first component you are trying, also can you add whole of App.js if possible. which version of vue you are using

Comment: @Saurabh, Yes, I have another component. Another component works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three fixes that I can see...

First, omit `name: 'AddFavoriteProduct'` in your component (it's not required for single-file components) and use [kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) for the component in your template. Second, you appear to be missing the `id-product` prop

```
<add-favorite-product :id-product="someProductIdFromSomewhere"></<add-favorite-product>
```

Third, you don't use interpolation in bound properties and you don't even need to pass anything other than the `$event` to your `addFavoriteProduct` method

```
@click="addFavoriteProduct($event)"
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It works. But when click button favorite, there exist error : `[vuex] unknown action type: addFavoriteProduct`

Comment: @mosestoh The error says `vuex` can't find the action `addFavoriteProduct`. Have you declared / defined the action in your vuex store?

Comment: @Donkarnash, Yes. the action in vuex store

Comment: @Phil, Seems I need you help again :) Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904428/how-to-update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing-on-the-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any error?

One mistake I see in your code is, you are taking one parameter: event, while you are trying to pass `{{ $product->id }}` to it, which seems a laravel variable. (Sorry, I don't know laravel)

If you want both event and `product->id` in method, you have to pass both parameters from HTML, like it is in [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers) with help of `$event`

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteProduct({{ $product->id }},  $event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        name: 'AddFavoriteProduct',  // I am not sure if name is needed, don't remember seeing it in docs
        props:['idProduct'],
        methods:{
            addFavoriteProduct(productId, event){
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_product: this.idProduct}
                this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteProduct', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Another problem is you are expecting a prop `idProduct`, which is not being passed to component, You have to pass it like this in [kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case):

```
<div class="panel panel-default panel-store-info">
    ...
    <div id="app">
        <AddFavoriteProduct id-product="4"></AddFavoriteProduct>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: Seems I need you help again :) Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904428/how-to-update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing-on-the-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

HTML is case-insensitive, so your custom button element `<AddFavoriteProduct></AddFavoriteProduct>` is being interpreted as your Vue warning reports: `<addfavoriteproduct>`

When you name your component with camelCase or PascalCase, the corresponding tag name you should be using in your markup should be kebab-cased like so:
`<add-favorite-product></add-favorite-product>`

Vue knows to do the conversion from "dash-letter" to "uppercase-letter".

Answer (score 1):

I am not used to `vuex`, as I generally implement my own store as a POJO object - not graduated with the learning curve of vuex. So can't provide a working solution with vuex, however to my knowledge, you need to kind of import the action(s) in your component - you can try the below

```
<template>
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteProduct({{ $product->id }},  $event)">
    <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
</a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['idProduct'],
        vuex: {
            actions: {
                setFavoriteProduct: setFavoriteProduct
                // assuming you named the action as setFavoriteProduct in vuex
                // avoid duplicate naming for easy debugging
            }
        }
        methods:{
            addFavoriteProduct(productId, event){
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_product: this.idProduct}
                // this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteProduct', payload)
                this.setFavoriteProduct(payload);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            }
        },
    }
```

Note: From Vuex2 the `store.dispatch()` accepts only one argument (not a problem with your current use case), however if you need to pass multiple arguments to your action you can work around like

```
store.dispatch('setSplitData',[data[0], data [1]])

// in the action:
setSplitData (context, [data1, data2]) { // uses ES6 argument destructuring

    OR

//... with an object:
store.dispatch('setSplitData',{ 
  data1: data[0], 
  data2: data [1],
})

// in the action:
setSplitData (context, { data1, data2 }) { // uses ES6 argument destructuring
//source: LinusBorg's comment at https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/366
```